# kernel panic virtualbox - slackware 14.1

Tags: virtualbox

As per subject am getting the error when booting both Slackware 14.1 and FreeBSD 9.2

This happened all of a sudden!

When booting FreeBSD I'm also getting the following error:

Can't work out which disk we are booting from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know for what reason but upgrading VirtualBox to latest version 4.3.6 solved the problem.